# Network not starting after new install of 16.04.2

Tags: networking, server, network-manager

I have just installed 16.04.2 on a new DELL server (using ubuntu-18.04.2-server-amd64.iso).  The install went without incident but after the reboot the network did not come up even though the install clearly was using it to get stuff from the repository.

Network is using static configuration (not DHCP).

Once I logged in on the console I started looking for the network config in /etc/network/interfaces and eventually found it in /etc/netplan ( it looked as expected -- address had a cidr block but I figured that was kosher as there was no netmask).

I failed to find anyway of restarting the network -- nothing in init.d or systemd??

In my searching I found reference to the need to create /etc/defauts/netplan which I did but the network still did not come up

Nothing useful in the logs, just the fact that network startup timed out.

Update:  I have just completed an install on an identical new system with the same result (the only difference was the IP address).

Two questions:
1/ how should I restart the network manually
2/ how can I find out what is actually failing

as requested (screenshots since I am working on virtual console (idrac):

top line reads "*-network:0"
[image: lshw 1st]

[image: lshw 2nd]

[image: cat netplan]

network/Interfaces has no non commented lines

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: This looks normal except that en03 appears to have no cable plugged in. Please describe your cabling. Is it cat 5e or cat 6? No /etc/defauts/netplan is required. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: Even though you said "new Dell server", do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and then go to the Dell support site and check for a newer BIOS, or firmware upgrades for the ethernet cards.

Comment: @heynnema . Thanks for your input!  I think I now know what the problem is:  ethtool shows no link!  I did not check this before because I assumed that the installer would have complained when I set up the interface and it should not have been able to complete the install.   I will get someone to check the cabling -- I don't have access to the data centre...  Actually they should be able to tell from the switch

Comment: @heynnema:  I *wil*l update when I have news ;)   This is a large corporate environment and I have to do stuff through other teams which takes time added to that work 3 days a week and when I'm not there kicking nothing happens.

Comment: @heynnema:   I have tracked the problem down to confusion over which interfaces were which.   In the end I simply went around and tried configuring each interface in turn.  One other thing that confused me is that ethtool does indicator or link does not appear to be accurate unless the network is configured.

Comment: At this point I am considering deleting the questions as it was based on the flawed assumption that "since install did not bitch about my network config then the at that point the network was active".  That assumption is wrong.  Install will silently ignore the config if the interface is down.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But you lost me. Was the cable plugged into the wrong port? Was the cable bad? Was the .yaml wrong? Are you working now?

Comment: @heynnema: The problem was simply that I was looking at the wrong interface and I assumed that ethtool would tell me if there was a link on the physical interface (I'm sure it used to ;) rather than the logical interface being "UP".   Since the server is in a remote data centre I could not simply "go and look".   Once I worked out what the real problem was fixing it was a matter of changing the interface name in the netplan file.

Comment: What interface did it end up being? Please show me your current .yaml. Do you want me to write an answer?